# Arduino Code: Expected '}' at end of input

Tags: c++, arduino

While I was coding in Arduino, the last lines of my code had issues. The program said that it

> expected declaration before '}' token

but I am not sure how to fix this. The code is down below and the error is in the last line of code. I am not sure why the last bracket that has the problem is not in the "box" or code, but the issue is still there.

```
void loop(){

 if(digitalRead(pirPin) == HIGH){
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state
   if(lockLow){  
     //makes sure we wait for a transition to LOW before any further output is made:
     lockLow = false;            
     Serial.println("---");
     Serial.print("motion detected at ");
     Serial.print(millis()/1000);
     Serial.println(" sec"); 
     delay(50);
     }         
     takeLowTime = true;
   }

 if(digitalRead(pirPin) == LOW){       
   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state

   if(takeLowTime){
    lowIn = millis();          //save the time of the transition from high to LOW
    takeLowTime = false;       //make sure this is only done at the start of a LOW phase
    }
   //if the sensor is low for more than the given pause, 
   //we assume that no more motion is going to happen
   if(!lockLow && millis() - lowIn > pause){  
       //makes sure this block of code is only executed again after 
       //a new motion sequence has been detected
       lockLow = true;  

            for (int pos1 = 0; pos1 <= 89; pos1 += 1)
          {
            servo1.write(pos1);
            delay(10);
          }
          for (int pos1 = 89; pos1 >= 1; pos1 -= 1)
          {
            servo1.write(pos1);
            delay(10);            
          }
       Serial.print("motion ended at ");      //output
       Serial.print((millis() - pause)/1000);
       Serial.println(" sec");
       delay(50);








       {

 if(digitalRead(pirPin) == HIGH){
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state
   if(lockLow){  
     //makes sure we wait for a transition to LOW before any further output is made:
     lockLow = false;            
     Serial.println("---");
     Serial.print("motion detected at ");
     Serial.print(millis()/1000);
     Serial.println(" sec"); 
     delay(50);
     }         
     takeLowTime = true;
   }

 if(digitalRead(pirPin) == LOW){       
   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state

   if(takeLowTime){
    lowIn = millis();          //save the time of the transition from high to LOW
    takeLowTime = false;       //make sure this is only done at the start of a LOW phase
    }
   //if the sensor is low for more than the given pause, 
   //we assume that no more motion is going to happen
   if(!lockLow && millis() - lowIn > pause){  
       //makes sure this block of code is only executed again after 
       //a new motion sequence has been detected
       lockLow = true;  

            for (int pos1 = 0; pos1 <= 89; pos1 += 1)
          {
            servo1.write(pos1);
            delay(10);
          }
          for (int pos1 = 89; pos1 >= 1; pos1 -= 1)
          {
            servo1.write(pos1);
            delay(10);            
          }
       Serial.print("motion ended at ");      //output
       Serial.print((millis() - pause)/1000);
       Serial.println(" sec");
       delay(50);



       }
   }
}       //THE ISSUE IS HERE
```

Comment: Indent it properly and you’ll probably find a stray curly brace or similar. Currently the indentation is so bad that no human can follow it

Comment: After the big gap (following a `delay(50);`) you've got an opening curly bracket, but I think you need a closing curly bracket?

Comment: The Arduino IDE provides the CTRL-T command to format / indent properly. This helps with wrong { } matching.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code through the UNIX `indent` tool.  It's available for most platforms.
The indentation is not just to keep it pretty, it keeps the code read-able.  Also there are many programmers editors that will find the "matching" bracket/parenthesis (e.g.: '%' in `vim`).

The code looks to me like it's missing an `if` condition or suchlike around `if ( digitalRead( pirPin ) == HIGH )`, since there's a block - or at least a section inside `{` with no clear reason for it.

Essentially your code is missing 3 lots of `}`, one of which is closing the aforementioned block.  It should not be hard to repair with a careful read-through.  But failing that, just add them at the end.

```
void loop(  )
{
    if ( digitalRead( pirPin ) == HIGH )
    {
        digitalWrite( ledPin, HIGH );   //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state
        if ( lockLow )
        {
            //makes sure we wait for a transition to LOW before any further output is made:
            lockLow = false;
            Serial.println( "---" );
            Serial.print( "motion detected at " );
            Serial.print( millis(  ) / 1000 );
            Serial.println( " sec" );
            delay( 50 );
        }
        takeLowTime = true;
    }

    if ( digitalRead( pirPin ) == LOW )
    {
        digitalWrite( ledPin, LOW );    //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state

        if ( takeLowTime )
        {
            lowIn = millis(  ); //save the time of the transition from high to LOW
            takeLowTime = false;        //make sure this is only done at the start of a LOW phase
        }
        //if the sensor is low for more than the given pause, 
        //we assume that no more motion is going to happen
        if ( !lockLow && millis(  ) - lowIn > pause )
        {
            //makes sure this block of code is only executed again after 
            //a new motion sequence has been detected
            lockLow = true;

            for ( int pos1 = 0; pos1 <= 89; pos1 += 1 )
            {
                servo1.write( pos1 );
                delay( 10 );
            }
            for ( int pos1 = 89; pos1 >= 1; pos1 -= 1 )
            {
                servo1.write( pos1 );
                delay( 10 );
            }
            Serial.print( "motion ended at " ); //output
            Serial.print( ( millis(  ) - pause ) / 1000 );
            Serial.println( " sec" );
            delay( 50 );

            {

                if ( digitalRead( pirPin ) == HIGH )
                {
                    digitalWrite( ledPin, HIGH );       //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state
                    if ( lockLow )
                    {
                        //makes sure we wait for a transition to LOW before any further output is made:
                        lockLow = false;
                        Serial.println( "---" );
                        Serial.print( "motion detected at " );
                        Serial.print( millis(  ) / 1000 );
                        Serial.println( " sec" );
                        delay( 50 );
                    }
                    takeLowTime = true;
                }

                if ( digitalRead( pirPin ) == LOW )
                {
                    digitalWrite( ledPin, LOW );        //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state

                    if ( takeLowTime )
                    {
                        lowIn = millis(  );     //save the time of the transition from high to LOW
                        takeLowTime = false;    //make sure this is only done at the start of a LOW phase
                    }
                    //if the sensor is low for more than the given pause, 
                    //we assume that no more motion is going to happen
                    if ( !lockLow && millis(  ) - lowIn > pause )
                    {
                        //makes sure this block of code is only executed again after 
                        //a new motion sequence has been detected
                        lockLow = true;

                        for ( int pos1 = 0; pos1 <= 89; pos1 += 1 )
                        {
                            servo1.write( pos1 );
                            delay( 10 );
                        }
                        for ( int pos1 = 89; pos1 >= 1; pos1 -= 1 )
                        {
                            servo1.write( pos1 );
                            delay( 10 );
                        }
                        Serial.print( "motion ended at " );     //output
                        Serial.print( ( millis(  ) - pause ) / 1000 );
                        Serial.println( " sec" );
                        delay( 50 );
                    }
                }
            }                   //THE ISSUE IS HERE
```

Answer (score -1):

This [online tool](http://www.balancebraces.com) can help you figure it out. I can see that at least two closing brackets are missing.

Also what people suggested here, to indent the code, is a very good advice.

Another way could be to refactor your code into smaller functions, working from the inner parts outwards.